Integers as polynomials in infinite variables
This question is more of a request for reference or ideas than else. Forgive (or correct) if there are imprecisions or blatant mistakes.
The main idea is that the unique factorization theorem for $\mathbb{Z}$ (and I think what follows could be generalized on any UFD with countably many primes) gives for an obvious correspondence between the algebra of polynomials in an infinite number of variables and $\mathbb{Z}$.
The question is how meaningful / useful this correspondence is, if tools from algebraic geometry can really give some insight or not, and how far one can get with this.
Discussion
Consider the infinite polynomial graded algebra $R=\mathbb{C}[x_i]_{i\ge 0}$ with $\text{deg}(x_i)=1$ for all $i$. Define an algebra homomorphism $\varphi : R \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by defining $\varphi(x_0) = 1$ and $\varphi(x_i)=p_i$ (the $i$-th prime number) for $i\ge1$.
For a monomial $x_I^\lambda = x_{i_0}^{\lambda_0}\cdots x_{i_n}^{\lambda_n}\in R$, define $\text{ev}_I^\lambda: R \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to be the $\mathbb{C}$-linear homomorphism defined by $\text{ev}_I^\lambda(x_I^\lambda)=1$ and $\text{ev}_I^\lambda(x_J^\mu)=0$ for $(I,\lambda)\neq(J,\mu)$, and define $$U := \bigcap_{I,\lambda}(\text{ev}_I^\lambda)^{-1}(\{-1,0,1\}).$$
In other words, $U$ is the set of polynomials with only coefficients $\pm 1$.
For $i\ge1$ define $K_i := U \cap \text{Ker}_i\varphi$ where $\text{Ker}_i\varphi$ is the $\mathbb{C}$-submodule of the homogeneous degree $i$ polynomials in $\text{Ker}\varphi$, and let $$K=\bigcup_{i\ge1}K_i.$$ Some examples
$$x_0+x_1-x_2\in K_1, \ x_1^2 + x_0x_1 - x_1x_2 \in K_2, \, \  x_1^3-x_0^2x_2-x_0^2x_3 \in K_3.$$ The ideal $I := (K) \subseteq R$ naturally inherits the grading of $R$.
Question: what can be said about $I$ or $\text{Proj}(R/I)$? It's clear that most of the natural numbers properties can be rephrased in terms of properties of $I$. For example:

Uniqueness of factorization: no element of any $K_i$ is a sum of two monomials.
Fermat's last theorem: there are no elements of the form $(x_I^{\lambda})^n-x_0^j(x_J^{\mu})^n-x_0^k(x_K^{\nu})^n \in K_i$ for any i and $n\ge3$.
Goldbach's conjecture: for every index set $I$ and exponent set $\lambda$ there exists integers $j$ and $k$ such that $$x_1x_I^\lambda-x_0^{|\lambda|}x_j-x_0^{|\lambda|}x_k \in K_{|\lambda|} $$
Twin primes conjecture There are infinitely many polynomials of the form $x_1 + x_i - x_j \in K_1$

But how far can one apply the methods of algebraic geometry to reformulate or approach number theory problems with this formalism? If you have some reference, that would be much appreciated.

I use a very similar idea in my "Special Algebraic Identities" collection except that I define $\varphi(x_n)=f(nx)$ where $f(x)$ is an odd real valued function such as sine or tangent.

I'm not aware of anything useful that this buys you, but there is a fun fact about Dirichlet series which is related to this: namely, you can show that the algebra of formal Dirichlet series $\sum a_n n^{-s}$ under Dirichlet convolution is isomorphic to the algebra of formal power series in countably many variables $p^{-s}$ where $p$ ranges over the primes. In particular it follows that Dirichlet series are an integral domain.

Thanks @QiaochuYuan! Indeed this is an old result, and the homomorphism I defined in the thread should be the composition of the inverse of this isomorphism (restricted to polynomials rather than formal power series) with the evaluation map that takes a Dirichlet series with a finite number of nonzero $a_n$'s to its complex value.
